# How can I link/or combine my three Django models to better maximize relationship and efficency

Tags: python, django

Im trying to model out my dB for my Django app.

I'm pretty content with that I have so far, only I have two questions regarding my models.

Here's a quick run-through of them.

`UserBuckets` contains every bucket a user has created.

`TotalBuckets` contains the total number of buckets a user has created.

`Bucket` Contains information for whats inside each user bucket.

```
class UserBuckets(models.Model):
    
    username = models.ForeignKey(UserModel.username)
    bucket_name = models.CharField()

    def get_all_buckets(self):
        all_buckets = UserBuckets.objects.all('bucket_name')
        return all_buckets

    def __str__(self):
        return self.bucket_name


class TotalBuckets(models.Model):

    username = models.ForeignKey(UserBuckets.username)
    total_buckets = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    def total_buckets_calc(self):
        self.total_buckets = TotalBuckets.objects.aggregate(Sum('bucket_name', distinct=True))
        self.save()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.total_buckets

class Bucket(models.Model):

    owner = models.ManyToManyField(UserBuckets.username)
    bucket = models.ForeignKeyField(UserBuckets.bucket_name, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    stocks = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=6),size=10) 
    stocks_in_bucket = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=True)

    def total_stocks_calc(self):
        self.stocks_in_bucket = Bucket.objects.aggregate(Sum('stocks_in_bucket', distinct=True))
        self.save()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("bucket:bucket-view", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.stocks
```

Here are my two questions:

`1.`I can see the argument of combining `UserBuckets` + `TotalBuckets`, however my only problem with that is the repeating the same datapoint for every new object that gets created. To keep things "clean", I separated them. Is this the "correct" procedure?

`2.` How can I properly reference that each `bucket` is an object based off of `UserBuckets`. I used a foreign key and a many-to-many key but doesn't that only cover the relationship basis?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need the User-object and the Bucket-objects related to the user to find every bucket the user has created and the number of buckets the user has.

```
class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField()

class Bucket(models.Model):

    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='buckets')
    stocks = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=6),size=10) 
    stocks_in_bucket = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=True)

    def total_stocks_calc(self):
        self.stocks_in_bucket = Bucket.objects.aggregate(Sum('stocks_in_bucket', distinct=True))
        self.save()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("bucket:bucket-view", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.stocks



EXAMPLE

user = User('Gabbeh')
b1 = Bucket(owner=user, ...)
b2 = Bucket(owner=user, ...)

all_buckets_owned_by_user = User.buckets()  # from related_name
all_buckets_owned_by_user = User.bucket_set()  # djangos naming wihtout setting related name
# or 
all_buckets_owned_by_user = Buckets.objects.filter(owner=user)

# To count just do .count() on the end of either query above.
```

Comment: This is much simpler than my original models, thank you. It wouldn't be necessary to add the Bucket name to `User` model?

Comment: No, that is not necessary. Django automatically adds an attribute to get all the buckets on the user. I believe this is normally `.bucket_set()` in you example.

If you are new to databases you should probably look up some intro videos on that, and that would make it easier to wrap your head around it in django as well.

Check the docs on [ForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey) and [Making queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/) for some docs on foreign keys and how it works. Mostly the latter.

Comment: Oh okay understood! Thank you for all the help and the links.